# How to speed up this code which works, but very slowly?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have this code but it runs far too slowly during the later procedures:

```
    Sub Here()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim srchLen, srchLen2, srchLen4, srchLen5, gName, nxtRw As Integer
    Dim g As Range

    'Clear Sheet 2 and Copy Column Headings
    Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
    'Determine length of Search Column from Sheet3
    srchLen = Sheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through list in Sheet3, Column A. As each value is
    'found in Sheet1, Column A, copy it top the next row in Sheet2

    With Sheets(1).Columns("A")
        For gName = 1 To srchLen
            Set g = .Find(Sheets(3).Range("A" & gName), lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not g Is Nothing Then
                nxtRw = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                g.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & nxtRw)
            End If
        Next
    End With

' stage 2 Check my Local Stocks
    srchLen2 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    srchLen4 = Sheets(4).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To srchLen4
        For j = 1 To srchLen2
            If Sheets(4).Rows(i).Columns(1).Value = Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(1).Value Then
                Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(2).Value = Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(2).Value + Sheets(4).Rows(i).Columns(2).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

'EBAY CODE
    srchLen2 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    srchLen5 = Sheets(5).Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To srchLen2
        For i = 1 To srchLen5
            If Sheets(5).Rows(i).Columns(11).Value = "" Then i = i + 1
                If Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(1).Value = Sheets(5).Rows(i).Columns(11).Value Then
                    Sheets(5).Rows(i).Columns(8).Value = Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(2).Value
                End If
        Next i
    Next j

'website CODE
    srchLen2 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    srchLen6 = Sheets(6).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To srchLen2
        For i = 1 To srchLen6
            If Sheets(6).Rows(i).Columns(7).Value = "" Then i = i + 1
                If Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(1).Value = Sheets(6).Rows(i).Columns(7).Value Then
                    Sheets(6).Rows(i).Columns(9).Value = Sheets(2).Rows(j).Columns(2).Value
                End If
        Next i
    Next j

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Call Calculate
    End Sub
```

Sheet 1 is a stocklist from our distributor containing about 65k items (columnA=SKUs) (ColumnB=Qty).

Sheet 2 is a results page where Sheet 3 is compared to Sheet 1 and if exists it's printed into sheet2, then row line is incremented to next line in a kind of loop.

Sheets 1,2,3 work quite well but the whole macro slows down when calculating past `' Stage 2 Check my local stocks`.

The eBay and website code seems to slow everything down probably due to the FOR NEXT loops.

I have uploaded a small version of [the Excel file](https://www.slogansclothing.co.uk/sample.xlsm) on our webserver. Please virus scan it prior to running it.

Copy paste this code into a macro and you should easily understand what it does and what I am trying to achieve.  It works for what I want but its darn slow.

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question, but are any of the cells formatted, i.e. font, as table, etc.?

Comment: Consider moving this question to codereview.stackexchange.com - they deal exclusively with improvements on code which currently works; that doesn't mean you can't look for help here, though.

Comment: Also your row counts should be `long` not variants

Answer (score 0):

Overall recommendation:

Convert your Excel Ranges into Arrays at the beginning of the procedure. Part of what's taking so much time is that Excel is accessing individual cells one at a time, which takes longer than accessing internal range data.

So for example, at the beginning of your procedure, create a class of objects called 'Website_Stock', with all the property you care about (index #, name, quantity, etc.), and then define an Array for the stock per the website. Then as you already do, calculate the first row and last row as you have above, but then say something along the lines of:

```
Redim Website_Stock(1 to lastrow)
Set  Website_Stock_Range to Range(Firstcolumn & firstrow, Lastcolumn & lastrow)
```

And then assign all your properties in your array according to your newly created range. Something like:

```
For i = 1 to lastrow
    Website_Stock(i).Index = Website_Stock_Range(x, y)
Next i
```

*This is pseudo code only

Then at the end of creating it, you can use your For loops as you have above, and it won't need to access your Excel sheet every time to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using ADO to query the sheets instead of loops will save you a lot of time, I made these changes and pasted the code below to run. I think it does what you were looking for!

1 Add Headers (SKU, Quantity to "imported List")

2 Add Headers (SKU, Quantity to "amazon result")

3 Add Headers (SKU to "Our products")

4 changed headers in "website upload" to number them instead of all "field data 1"

4 Add worksheet called "dump"

5 Add this code to module and run

```
Const SourceDirectory As String = "C:\MyDirectory"
Const Filename As String = "sample.xlsm"
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sub Here()
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
AddHeadersToAmazonResult
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & SourceDirectory & Filename & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
rs.Open "Select il.* FROM ([imported list$] il INNER JOIN [Our products$] op on il.SKU=op.SKU)", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Sheets("amazon result").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

''check stocks
rs.Open "SELECT ar.SKU, iif(isnull(ar.Quantity),0,ar.Quantity)+iif(isnull(hs.Quantity),0,hs.Quantity) " & _
        "FROM ( [amazon result$] ar LEFT JOIN  [holding stock$] hs on ar.SKU=hs.SKU)", _
        con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
i = 2
While Not rs.EOF
    Sheets("amazon result").Cells(i, 1) = rs(0).Value
    Sheets("amazon result").Cells(i, 2) = rs(1).Value
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Wend
rs.Close    

''ebay
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Amazon result$]", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
Set ws = Sheets("ebay upload")
LastRow = ws.Cells(65000, 11).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To LastRow
If ws.Cells(r, 11).Value <> "" Then
    rs.Filter = "SKU='" & ws.Cells(r, 11).Value & "'"
    ws.Cells(r, 8).Value = rs(1)
End If
Next r
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing 'killing here because it messes up the next query if you leave it open
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


''website

rs.Open "SELECT [field data 1], [field data 2], [field data 3], [field data 4], [field data 5], [field data 6], [field data 7], [field data 8], SKU, [field data 10], [field data 11], [field data 12] " & _
        "FROM ([website upload$] wu LEFT JOIN [amazon result$] ar " & _
        "ON wu.[field data 7]=ar.SKU)", _
        con, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Sheets("dump").Cells.Clear
    Sheets("dump").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    Sheets("website upload").Rows("2:65000").Clear
    Sheets("dump").UsedRange.Copy Sheets("website upload").Cells(2, 1)
End If
rs.Close


GoTo cleanup

errorhandler:
MsgBox "There was an error." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical

cleanup:
If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
If con.State = adStateOpen Then con.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

End Sub

Sub AddHeadersToAmazonResult()
Sheets("amazon result").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("amazon result").Cells(1, 1) = "SKU"
Sheets("amazon result").Cells(1, 2) = "Quantity"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some coding suggestions - might not help the speed, can't tell until you try with the full dataset.

Use `Option Explicit` so you know if you are using a variable properly

`roboCode' sub generate some code to make sheet references more generic. Run it once to generate the code and copy it to the proper locations - a module call wks and a sub init().

Using Worksheet numbers is a very bad idea. roboCode will allow you to address via names.

Capture your errors.

Do not use one line for dim statements - results it objects/variants, not the type of the last variable.

Use longs for row counts/indexes.

Try using .Cells for Range addressing. Easier to write code, and clearer.

Use indenting - highlight rows and use Tab and shift-Tab to control indent

Keep outside informed of progress via status bar, call DoEvents once in a while to allow other processes to run and for the screen to update. You'll see this code get slower as it progresses (based on sample.xls) - I think the Find is the culprit. You might consider a VB.Net solution instead of Excel VBA. Access may be even better.

Other comments inline

```
Option Explicit

Sub roboCode()
    ' name worksheets
    Dim i As Integer
    Debug.Print "' global dim in module named 'wks'"
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Debug.Print "public wks" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name, " ", "_") & " as worksheet"
    Next i
    Debug.Print "' one time Set"
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Debug.Print "set wks" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name, " ", "_") & " = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(""" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name & """)"
    Next i
End Sub
Sub Init()
    ' text from roboCode
    Set wks.Imported_list = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("imported list")
    Set wks.Amazon_result = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("amazon result")
    Set wks.Our_products = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Our products")
    Set wks.Holding_stock = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("holding stock")
    Set wks.Ebay_upload = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ebay upload")
    Set wks.Website_upload = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("website upload")
    Set wks.Personalised_Goods = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Personalised Goods")
    Set wks.Manual_checks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Manual checks")
End Sub
Function RowCount(wks As Worksheet) As Long
    RowCount = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
Function ColCount(wks As Worksheet) As Long
    ColCount = wks.UsedRange.Columns.Count
End Function
Sub Here()
On Error GoTo Local_error

    Init
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'    Dim srchLen, srchLen2, srchLen4, srchLen5, gName, nxtRw As Integer ' all Objects/Variants except nxtRw
    Dim srchLen As Long
    Dim srchLen2 As Long
    Dim srchLen4 As Long
    Dim srchLen5 As Long
    Dim srchLen6 As Long
    Dim gName As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim nxtRw As Long

    'Clear Sheet 2 and Copy Column Headings
'    wks.Ebay_upload.Cells.ClearContents
    wks.Ebay_upload.UsedRange.Delete (xlUp)

    'Determine length of Search Column from Sheet3
'    srchLen = Sheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    srchLen = wks.Our_products.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' not used, RowCount() used instead

    'Loop through list in Sheet3, Column A. As each value is
    'found in Sheet1, Column A, copy it top the next row in Sheet2

    With wks.Imported_list.Columns(1)
        nxtRw = 1
        For gName = 1 To RowCount(wks.Our_products)
            ' I think this next statement is slowing things down, may be unavoidable
            Set rng = .Find(wks.Our_products.Cells(gName, 1))
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                nxtRw = nxtRw + 1
                ' copy may be slower than individual assigments
'                rng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wks.Amazon_result.Rows(nxtRw)
                wks.Amazon_result.Cells(nxtRw, 1) = rng.Value
                If nxtRw Mod 100 = 0 Then
                    Application.StatusBar = nxtRw
                    DoEvents
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' ....
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
Local_exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Exit Sub
Local_error:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description ' hit ctrl-break if you get here, then set next to Resume for debug
    Resume Local_exit
    Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this code, ran the roboCode first but upon running the init i get a variable not defined error.  I'll relook at it when I get more time but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the file provided

- Posted code: about 32 minutes
- This solution: about 2 minutes

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HereArrays()
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long, t As Double, t1 As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    t = Timer: t1 = t
    'Clear Sheet 2
    Sheets(2).UsedRange.EntireColumn.Delete

    lr1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = lr1
    lr3 = Sheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:B" & lr1)
    v2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1:B" & lr1)
    v3 = Sheets(3).Range("A1:B" & lr3)
    i2 = 1
    For i3 = 1 To lr3
        For i1 = 1 To lr1
            If v3(i3, 1) = v1(i1, 1) Then
                v2(i2, 1) = v1(i1, 1)
                v2(i2, 2) = v1(i1, 2)
                i2 = i2 + 1
                Exit For            'exit inner For only
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Sheets(2).Range("A1:B" & lr2) = v2
    Debug.Print "HereArrays - 1 of 4 - Duration: " & Timer - t & " seconds"
    t = Timer

    ' stage 2 Check my Local Stocks
    lr1 = Sheets(4).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v1 = Sheets(4).Range("A1:B" & lr1)
    v2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1:B" & lr2)
    For i1 = 1 To lr1
        For i2 = 1 To lr2
            If v1(i1, 1) = v2(i2, 1) Then
                v2(i2, 2) = v2(i2, 2) + v1(i1, 2)
                Exit For            'exit inner For only
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Sheets(2).Range("A1:B" & lr2) = v2
    Debug.Print "HereArrays - 2 of 4 - Duration: " & Timer - t & " seconds"
    t = Timer

    'EBAY CODE
    lr1 = Sheets(5).Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v1 = Sheets(5).Range("K1:K" & lr1)
    v3 = Sheets(5).Range("H1:H" & lr1)
    v2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1:B" & lr2)
    For i2 = 1 To lr2
        For i1 = 1 To lr1
            If Len(v1(i1, 1)) = 0 Then i1 = i1 + 1
            If v2(i2, 1) = v1(i1, 1) Then
                v3(i1, 1) = v2(i2, 2)
                Exit For            'exit inner For only
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Sheets(5).Range("H1:H" & lr1) = v3
    Debug.Print "HereArrays - 3 of 4 - Duration: " & Timer - t & " seconds"
    t = Timer

    'website CODE
    lr1 = Sheets(6).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v1 = Sheets(6).Range("G1:G" & lr1)
    v3 = Sheets(6).Range("I1:I" & lr1)
    v2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1:B" & lr2)
    For i2 = 1 To lr2
        For i1 = 1 To lr1
            If Len(v1(i1, 1)) = 0 Then i1 = i1 + 1
            If v2(i2, 1) = v1(i1, 1) Then
                v3(i1, 1) = v2(i2, 2)
                Exit For            'exit inner For only
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Sheets(6).Range("I1:I" & lr1) = v3
    Debug.Print "HereArrays - 4 of 4 - Duration: " & Timer - t & " seconds"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Call Calculate

    Debug.Print "HereArrays - Total  - Duration: " & Timer - t1 & " seconds"
    'HereArrays - 1 of 4 - Duration: 86.2109375 seconds
    'HereArrays - 2 of 4 - Duration: 0.328125 seconds
    'HereArrays - 3 of 4 - Duration: 0.25 seconds
    'HereArrays - 4 of 4 - Duration: 16.47265625 seconds
    'HereArrays - Total  - Duration: 103.26171875 seconds
End Sub
```

---

Basically, this is the initial code "translated" to use arrays instead of interacting with Ranges

Detailed measurements

Posted code:

```
'Here - 1 of 4 - Duration: 654.28515625 seconds

'Here - 2 of 4 - Duration: 24.5078125 seconds
'Here - 3 of 4 - Duration: 13.43359375 seconds
'Here - 4 of 4 - Duration: 1195.375 seconds

'Here - Total  - Duration: 1887.6015625 seconds
```

---

This code:

```
'HereArrays - 1 of 4 - Duration: 86.2109375 seconds

'HereArrays - 2 of 4 - Duration: 0.328125 seconds
'HereArrays - 3 of 4 - Duration: 0.25 seconds
'HereArrays - 4 of 4 - Duration: 16.47265625 seconds

'HereArrays - Total  - Duration: 103.26171875 seconds
```